# When the Typo3 extension is compatible with Typo3 V12, it can be successfully installed, but the content will not be rendered

Tags: typo3-12.x

I have a Typo3 plug-in canto_extension, and I am currently maintaining it to adapt it to Typo3 V12. I have made some changes to solve the errors reported during the installation process. But now I have encountered a problem :The plug-in can be successfully installed in V12.4.6, but I found through the log that the InlineControlContainerz.php registered with the following code is not executed.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['formEngine']['nodeRegistry'][number] = [
    'nodeName' => 'inline',
    'priority' => 60, 
    'class' => \CantoVendor\CantoExtension\Backend\InlineControlContainer::class,
];
```

In addition, when installing in V12.1.1, an error message appears: Extension canto_extension is not available. I checked the version dependencies of ext_emconf.php and composer.json and everything looks fine.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation and please give me some advice?